# col-10 and col-2 row generate weird spacing on right in bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this very simple code:

```
<body>
    <div class="myclass">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-10">Blah</div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div>Hello </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I load up firefox and I see that the row takes up some extra space on the right. This causes a horizontal scrollbar on the bottom because the browser thinks the site width is very wide. Here is a photo:

[image: spacing issue]

Shouldn't row take up to col-12 just fine? col-10 + col-2 adds up to col-12, so why am I getting extra space?

Comment: Where's your .container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your `.row` in a `.container`.

or add `padding: 0 15px;` to your `myclass`.

```
.myclass{
    padding: 0 15px;
}
```

> Grids and full-width layouts -
>   Folks looking to create fully fluid layouts (meaning your site stretches the entire width of the viewport) must wrap their grid content in a containing element with padding: 0 15px; to offset the margin: 0 -15px; used on .rows.